# MICO CORBA server with corbaloc access

Tags: c++, corba

I'm using MICO to create a C++ CORBA server.

In my system a client should be able to directly access the corba object in the server using a corbaloc address (no name service).
Do you know if MICO provides such feature? How can I implement that? I tried with:

```
ORB_ptr orb = CORBA::ORB_init (argc, argv, "mico-local-orb");
Object_var obj = orb -> resolve_initial_references( "RootPOA" );
PortableServer::POA_var poa = PortableServer::POA::_narrow( obj );
PortableServer::POAManager_var pman = poa -> the_POAManager();
pman -> activate();

PortableServer::ObjectId_var oid = PortableServer::string_to_ObjectId( "hello" );

HelloImpl* servant = new HelloImpl();

poa -> activate_object_with_id( oid.in(), servant );
servant -> _remove_ref();

orb -> run();
```

this code works with OMNIORB but not with MICO.

EDIT: I also tried with a persistent lifespan policy but it doesn't work either:

```
ORB_ptr orb = ORB_init( argc, argv );
Object_var obj = orb -> resolve_initial_references( "RootPOA" );
PortableServer::POA_var poa = PortableServer::POA::_narrow( obj );
PortableServer::POAManager_var pman = poa -> the_POAManager();
pman -> activate();

PortableServer::LifespanPolicy_var lifespan = 
    poa -> create_lifespan_policy( PortableServer::PERSISTENT );
PortableServer::IdAssignmentPolicy_var idassignment = 
    poa ->  create_id_assignment_policy ( PortableServer::USER_ID );
CORBA::PolicyList policies( 2 );
policies.length( 2 );
policies[0] = PortableServer::IdAssignmentPolicy::_duplicate( idassignment );
policies[1] = PortableServer::LifespanPolicy::_duplicate( lifespan );
PortableServer::POA_var child_poa = 
    poa -> create_POA( "childPOA", pman.in(), policies );
PortableServer::POAManager_var child_pman = child_poa -> the_POAManager();
child_pman -> activate();

idassignment -> destroy();
lifespan -> destroy();

HelloImpl* servant = new HelloImpl();

PortableServer::ObjectId_var oid = child_poa -> activate_object( servant );
CORBA::Object_var ref = child_poa -> id_to_reference( oid.in() );
PortableServer::ObjectId_var oid = PortableServer::string_to_ObjectId( "hello" );
child_poa -> activate_object_with_id ( oid.in (), servant );

orb -> run();
```

EDIT2:
I tested the server with a client that tries to `string_to_object` the following corbaloc addresses:

- `corbaloc:iiop:localhost:12345/hello`
- `corbaloc:iiop:localhost:12345/childPOA/hello`

but none of them worked. I always get a `CORBA::OBJECT_NOT_EXIST` exception.

Thanks

Comment: @Reimeus I tried also with the persistent lifespan policy (I added the  code to my question). But it doesn't work either.

Comment: What exactly does not work and how do you examined that?

Comment: @tuergeist I wrote a client that use `ORB::string_to_object` to resolve the corbaloc address `corbaloc:iiop:localhost:12345/hello` but it can't find the remote object.

Comment: What kind of exceptio did you get? Object_not_found / exists ? or TRANSIENT ?

Comment: @tuergeist I get a `CORBA::OBJECT_NOT_EXIST` exception.

Comment: @Daniele You have to submit the poa hierarchy in the corbaloc. I'll guess (I have no mico compiled here) `...ocalhost:12345/childPOA/hello`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mico you have to use the poa hierarchy in the corbalo url as well. For your example `corbaloc::localhost:12345/childPOA/hello` should work.

See also [the Diploma thesis of Frank Pilhofer, the implementor of Mico's POA](http://www.fpx.de/fp/Uni/Diplom/node32.html), which states

```
 create a persistent POA with the name ``MyPOA'', and then activate an object 
 using the ``MyObject'' Object Id, you could refer to that object using the IOR

  iioploc://thishost:1234/MyService/MyPOA/MyObject
```

Edit: You have to start your serving executable with a service name `-POAImplName MyService`

Comment: I tried `corbaloc::localhost:12345/childPOA/hello` but I always get a `CORBA::OBJECT_NOT_EXIST` exception

Comment: It worked, thanks. I had to launch the server with `server.exe -ORBIIOPAddr inet:localhost:12345 -POAImplName MyService` and the client with `client.exe corbaloc::localhost:12345/MyService/childPOA/hello`